# Formatear leyenda gráfico con leaflet en R

Tags: r

Hola compañeras y compañeros!

No logro formatear los intervalos numéricos de la leyenda en un gráfico realizado con leaflet en R.

La variable `geomunicipios$Renta.media.por.hogar.2016`
tiene, como separador de millar "," y como separador decimal "."

Necesito el formato ##000.000.000,00

```
addLegend(pal = pal, values =  ~ geomunicipios$Renta.media.por.hogar.2016,
            position = "bottomright",
            opacity = 1,
            labFormat = labelFormat(suffix = "€"),
            title = "Renta Media Hogares (2016)")
```

Gracias. Saludos.

Comment: ¿La variable `Renta.media.por.hogar.2016` es numérica? ¿Que rango de valores maneja?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar las siguiente función en lugar de labelFormat

```
labelFormat_decimal <- function (prefix = "", suffix = "", between = " &ndash; ", digits = 3, 
                                 big.mark = ",", transform = identity, decimal.mark = "."){
  formatNum <- function(x) {
    format(round(transform(x), digits), trim = TRUE, scientific = FALSE, 
           big.mark = big.mark, decimal.mark = decimal.mark,nsmall=digits)
  }
  function(type, ...) {
    switch(type, numeric = (function(cuts) {
      paste0(prefix, formatNum(cuts), suffix)
    })(...), bin = (function(cuts) {
      n <- length(cuts)
      paste0(prefix, formatNum(cuts[-n]), between, formatNum(cuts[-1]), 
             suffix)
    })(...), quantile = (function(cuts, p) {
      n <- length(cuts)
      p <- paste0(round(p * 100), "%")
      cuts <- paste0(formatNum(cuts[-n]), between, formatNum(cuts[-1]))
      paste0("<span title=\"", cuts, "\">", prefix, p[-n], 
             between, p[-1], suffix, "</span>")
    })(...), factor = (function(cuts) {
      paste0(prefix, as.character(transform(cuts)), suffix)
    })(...))
  }
}
```

Sólo pasa los parametros que necesitas

```
addLegend(pal = pal, values =  ~ geomunicipios$Renta.media.por.hogar.2016,
            position = "bottomright",
            opacity = 1,
            labFormat = labelFormat_decimal(suffix = "€", decimal.mark=",",
                                    digits = 2, big.mark = "."),
            title = "Renta Media Hogares (2016)")
```

Comment: +1 pero no estaría mal que cites la fuente de este código. Saludos.

Comment: Claro esta función la encontre en https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/455 sólo agregue nsmall=digits