# Formato numérico con "," como marcador decimal en Leaflet y R

Tags: r

Hola compañeras y compañeros,

No logro formatear una leyenda de un mapa creado con Leaflet en R, que utiliza intervalos de la variable `geomunicipios$Renta.media.por.hogar.2016`

```
bins <-  quantile(geomunicipios$Renta.media.por.hogar.2016, probs = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1))
pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = ~ geomunicipios$Renta.media.por.hogar.2016, bins = bins)

addLegend(pal = pal, values =  ~ geomunicipios$Renta.media.por.hogar.2016,
            position = "bottomright",
            opacity = 1,
            labFormat = labelFormat(suffix = "€"),
            title = "Renta Media Hogares (2016)")
```

Necesito pasar al formato #00.000,00 o simplemente #00.000

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: No hqas preguntado lo mismo aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326536/formatear-leyenda-gr%c3%a1fico-con-leaflet-en-r? Ayudaría por ejemplo si aclararas algo que te pregunte en esta misma pregunta

Comment: Gracias por tu interés,
Esa primera pregunta que hice, que es la misma que esta no está asociada a mi usuario y por eso la volví a hacer.

Comment: Tampoco puedo comentar en esa pregunta (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326536/formatear-leyenda-gr%c3%a1fico-con-leaflet-en-r).

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, la variable ```Renta.media.por.hogar.2016```,  este es el primer intervalo, 19,794.0 – 21,506.4€, y este el último  24,715.2 – 29,812.0€

Comment: Ok, entonces estás trabajando con intervalos ya preestablecidos, revisa la respuesta de Rolando en esta tu otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326536/formatear-leyenda-gr%c3%a1fico-con-leaflet-en-r ya que resuelve esto. No veía la necesidad de mostrar decimales inicialmente. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, la respuesta de esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326536/formatear-leyenda-gr%c3%a1fico-con-leaflet-en-r (que es la misma que esta, pero la tuve que hacer porque la primera no quedó asociada a mi usuario) es correcta. Gracias.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, pido disculpas por este enredo.

Comment: No hay problema José ;-), te sugiero que elimines esta pregunta, no tiene sentido duplicar el contenido, por otro lado si la anterior ha respondido tu pregunta aceptale la respuesta a Rolando. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que [acabar de definir](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.0.3/topics/addLegend) el `labFormat` añadiendo `big.mark = ".", decimal.mark=","`

```
addLegend(pal = pal, values =  ~ geomunicipios$Renta.media.por.hogar.2016,
            position = "bottomright",
            opacity = 1,
            labFormat = labelFormat(suffix = "€", big.mark = ".", decimal.mark=","),
            title = "Renta Media Hogares (2016)")
```

Comment: Obtengo este error:
In prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  :
  'big.mark' and 'decimal.mark' are both '.', which could be confusing

Comment: @JoséCarlos, El error es que internamente la función maneja el punto como separador de decimales, `big.mark` es el separador de miles, por lo que ambos terminan siendo el mismo caracter, de ahí este error. El problema es un tema de concepto que me gustaría explicarlo, de ahí que en la pregunta que hiciste originalmente te preguntaba acerca de los datos que estás graficando.

Comment: @Jose Carlos, mis disculpas, copié mal lo que pretendía, lo he cambiado en la respuesta.

Comment: @RogerTorné, esta función no tiene parámetro `decimal.mark` de ahí el problema,  tampoco va a funcionar. La pregunta original de José ya tiene una respuesta que resuelve el problema.